# Sorting lists by only using the numbers in the value

Tags: python, list, sorting

let's say i have this list

```
a = ['20 - A', '200 - A', '30 - B']
```

and i want to sort it in a way that will sort by the numbers
like so:

```
['20 - A', '30 - B', '200 - A']
```

i know i can split the values by finding the first space but i can't think of a way to sort it after i do

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> a = ['20 - A', '200 - A', '30 - B']
>>> sorted(a, key = lambda x: int(x.split()[0]))

>>> ['20 - A', '30 - B', '200 - A']
```

Comment: I am new to Python and I fell in love instantly